# My firewall rules are not working

Tags: iptables, firewall, logging

I am trying to write firewall rules for logging messages but they don't seem to work:

First of all I have added a chain MY_LOG

> **-N MY_LOG**

Then I wrote a rule to jump to MY_LOG chain when I receive a message with destination IP 192.168.1.132, destination port 79 and protocol UDP:

> **-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.132/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 79 -j MY_LOG**

and finally I wrote the rule for the MY_LOG chain:

> **-A MY_LOG -m mark --mark 0x35 -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix  "MY LOG " --nflog-group 30**

Then I am sending messages to the correspoding IP and port using Netcat:

> nc -u 192.168.1.132 79

but it is not logging anything. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your IPTABLES rule is for destination-port 79, but your `nc -u` command is for port 89.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in reporting the command, in my tests I used port 79 with nc.